# How to Query fresh attached RelatedEntityList<T> before commit

Tags: devforce

The user in our application has the possibility to add, delete and modify an object graph.

I am using Cocktail's UnitOfWork to collect the changed Entitys and start a "BusinessProcess" to check for certain entrys in the Object Graph.

Lets say, i want to Check, if the user has added an Entry in the Person.Department, where Department is an RelatedEntityList of Person.

The user has added the Department on the Person.Department and i am using Linq to check weather there is a special Department of "Administrator".

My Linq Query looks like this.

var adminDepartement = person.Departement.Where(x=>x.Name.Equals("Administrator")).FirstOrDefault();

This query works great, if the departement was already there.
But when the user has just added the departement with this session, i get a null back from the RelatedEntityList.

Is there any trick to search via Linq for new added entrys?

Or do i have to work with the EntityManager directly?

On the second Save, the Linq Query returns the adminDepartement correctly, but i need this validation before the user saves.

Answer (score 1):

I found my issue. I was Querying on the EntityId Person.Department.Id wich is 0 when the entity is created, and be set at database level, when the commit has finished.

I am now using Person.DepartementId to query for existing entrys.